# How to connect frontend and backend on domain

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, backend

I don't really have experience with backend and how things work together. I have created a simple live message sending app with `node.js` and `socket.io`. When I host a static web server on my machine (`http-server` which runs on local port using node.js) my app works perfectly fine but when I upload it on my host or github pages just for test, the backend doesn't seem to work. I uploaded all my files with an FTP program and the frontend loads fine but the backend doesn't. Do I have to know something like Django or ASP.NET to make these work on my host?

EDIT: One more thing, first line in my `server.js` is `const io = require('socket.io')(3000)`and in my `script.js` - `const socket = io('http://localhost:3000')`where **3000** and **localhost:3000** stands for local host in my machine. What do i need to put instead of these?

Comment: Do you get any HTTP response from your backend (like an error 404 or 500)?

Comment: Nothing, when i input something in my input field, the page seems to continuously refresh (in the corner of the window) but it actually doesn't

Comment: Did you try with cPanel ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably need to install and setup Node.js on your server, contact yout hosting provider for node installation if the option isn't available in yout cPanel.

Comment: Doesn't all "serious" host-service providers provide node.js support by now?